# How to match the name by the id from multiple arrays in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, filter, foreach

My React application receives an array consisting of one array which holds the ids of two others, and two arrays which contain the id and the name. I want to create one array, which holds the names which fit to the id from array one. Written in an censored form it looks like this:

There is array A, which consists of two ids and the own id (AAAAA_id).

A
{
"AAAAAA_id": "AA",
"BBBBBB_id": "BB",
"CCCCCC_id": "CC"
}

Than there is Array B which consists of BBBBBB_id and the name.

B
{
"BBBBBB_id": "BB",
"BBBBBB_name": "BName",
}

Furthermore there is Array C which consists of CCCCCC_id and the name

C
{
"CCCCCC_id": "CC",
"CCCCCC_name": "CName",
}

How can I achieve an new Array D which consists of

D
{
"AAAAAA_id": "AA",
"BBBBBB_id": "BB",
"BBBBBB_name": "BName",
"CCCCCC_id": "CC"
"CCCCCC_name": "CName",
}

Id did start with a combination of map and filter,

`const D = A.map(x => {`

But I don't know how to progress from here on to handle multiple arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```
const D = A.map(a => ({
    ...a,
    BBBBBB_name: B.find(b => b.BBBBBB_id == a.BBBBBB_id)?.BBBBBB_name,
    CCCCCC_name: C.find(c => c.CCCCCC_id == a.CCCCCC_id)?.CCCCCC_name,
}))
```

or better performance solution

```
const MAP_ID_NAME_B = B.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.BBBBBB_id] = cur.BBBBBB_name
    return acc;
}, {})

const MAP_ID_NAME_C = C.reduce((acc, cur) => {
    acc[cur.CCCCCC_id] = cur.CCCCCC_name
    return acc;
}, {})

const D = A.map(a => ({
    ...a,
    BBBBBB_name: MAP_ID_NAME_B[a.BBBBBB_id],
    CCCCCC_name: MAP_ID_NAME_C[a.CCCCCC_id]
}));
```